# My Discord bot's command suddenly stopped listening to my arg hints, then stopped working altogether

Tags: discord.py

I'm trying to write a command to collect free agent offers in our local basketball simulation server into CSV format so we can go through them more quickly and efficiently. I wrote this command to take the offers, but suddenly, my arguments stopped listening to the hints I gave:

`async def offer(ctx, firstName: str, lastName: str, amount: float, length: int, option: str='no', ntc: str='no'):`

It allows integers to be used for lastName, even though I used these hints here. It was working normally, except that it didn't throw errors if you used the wrong type of input, and then suddenly my Discord bot stops responding to this command altogether. It still responds correctly to other commands, so something is wrong with this command specifically, and I can't figure it out...

Here's the full command:

```
@bot.command()
async def offer(ctx, firstName: str, lastName: str, amount: float, length: int, option: str='no', ntc: str='no'):

    team = ctx.channel.category.name
    username = ctx.author.name
    usermention = ctx.author.mention
    userid = ctx.author.id

    if option.lower() == 'po' or option.lower() == 'yes': option = 'yes'
    else: option = 'no'
    if ntc.lower() == 'ntc' or ntc.lower() == 'yes': ntc = 'yes'
    else: ntc = 'no'

    offer = (str(team) + ',' + str(username) + ',' + str(userid) + ',' + str(firstName) + ' ' + str(lastName) + ',' + str(amount) + ',' + str(length) + ',' + str(option) + ',' + str(ntc))
    offersList.append(offer)

    baseText = ('The ' + team + ' (' + usermention + ') offered ' + firstName + ' ' + lastName + ' a $' + str(amount) + ' million contract for ' + str(length) + ' years')
    if option == 'no' and ntc == 'no': text = (baseText + '.')
    if option == 'no' and ntc == 'yes': text = (baseText + ' with an NTC.')
    if option == 'yes' and ntc == 'no': text = (baseText + ' with a player option.')
    if option == 'yes' and ntc == 'yes': text = (baseText + ' with a player option and an NTC.')
    print(text)
    await ctx.send(text)
```

Please let me know if it's something obvious, or I have to rethink this command altogether... thanks everyone!

Comment: Did you try to print something at the beginning of the command?
and what happens when you try to execute the command, does it tell you command not found or what error does it throw?

Comment: As soon as I put a print line at the top, the whole command suddenly worked. Was it caught on something, and needed print to actually execute? I don't understand...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahmed asked if it executed a print function at the beginning of the command. Once I added this print function, suddenly the whole command started working again. I'm not sure why, but it's working... so I won't touch it. lol. thanks guys.

Comment: I don't understand either lol, I was telling you to do this so we can check if the function is being called or not XD, but happy to hear that it worked.

Would you try to remove it and tell me what happens so we can understand?
and if you can upvote my comment or sth if it was helpful XD